# How to do keybinding in eclipse rcp?

Tags: eclipse-rcp

How to do keybinding in eclipse RCP?

I mean how to use key sequences in your GUI...like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>something</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>something</kbd>.....?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can look at the [Eclipse Command tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20120408140013/http://www.vogella.de:80/articles/EclipseCommands/article.html#keybinding)

> To define and use your own scheme you need:

- Define a scheme in extension point "org.eclipse.ui.bindings"
- Assign this scheme to the keybindings you defined
- Have a product created
- Define the file "plugin_customization.ini" and set the scheme for the product via a property.

[alt text http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseCommands/images/keybinding10.gif](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseCommands/images/keybinding10.gif)

---

the all keybinding mechanism is based on the [Eclipse Command Framework](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Platform_Command_Framework)

[image]
<sub>(source: [eclipse.org](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/index.cgi/platform-ui-home/R3_1/contributions-proposal/requestForComments_html_m41374bdb.png?view=co))</sub>

Comment: +1 for the explanation and the answer i was also looking for key binding. thanks Buddy:)